# How to use Slim (or haml) directly with Rack?

Tags: ruby, routes, rack, slim-lang

In Sinatra, it's pretty easy to render a slim template upon request:

```
get '/some_request' do
  slim :file_name
end
```

Since Rack expects a class with a `.call` method which then returns `[status, headers, [body]]` array, like:

```
class RequestManager
  def call(env)
    return [200, {}, ['why am I in an array?']]
  end
end
```

**How do I return the rendered slim template to make Rack happy?**

e.g. `[200, {}, '<html><head></head><!-- you get the idea --></html>']`

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this by including the haml gem in your config.ru,
then using

```
require 'haml' # or put haml in your gemfile and start rack with `bundle exec`
# ...
run lambda {|env|
  template = File.read(path)
  page = Haml::Engine.new(template).render()
}
# ...
```

to set your `page` attribute from your template.